# jQuery loading content in div onClick

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, load

I have pages in my 'inc' folder, when I hit the 'trigger', #wrapper will load the selected page into the #wrapper. The problem I have is;

Whenever I click on 'trigger' outside of the #wrapper it works. And the content will load into the #wrapper. But when I have the 'trigger' inside of the #wrapper it won't work.

I'm stuck on this for a while.

The JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Initial
    $('#wrapper').load('inc/home.php');
});

$(document).ready(function() {

    // Set trigger and container variables
    var trigger = $('#test a'),
        container = $('#wrapper');

    // Fire on click
    trigger.click(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('href'); 

        // Begin fade
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#wrapper').css("opacity", "0"); }, 0);

        // Load target page into container
        setTimeout(function(){ container.load('inc/' + target + '.php'); }, 400);

        // End fade
        setTimeout(function(){ $('#wrapper').css("opacity", "1"); }, 900);

        // Stop normal link behavior
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: If you mean that your trigger element is inside the #wrapper div and the html that is loaded, then you are destroying and creating a new element each time you do a `.load()` call. Event listeners are not persistent across new instances of elements. Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements](/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because the element was not available, hence, the event was never binded. You can try following using [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) callback.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var container = $('#wrapper');
  container .load('inc/home.php', function() {
    var trigger = $('#test a');

    trigger.click(function() {
      // your code here
    });
  });
});
```

Alternatively, you can use [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for dynamic elements

Update from

```
trigger.click(function() {
```

to

```
container.on("click", "#test a", function() {
```

Comment: This fixed the problem, but only for the first click inside the #wrapper works

Comment: Not clear with statement - `Only for the first click`. Can you please explain.

Comment: When I onClick on 'trigger' outside of the #wrapper it works fine, when I click on 'trigger' inside of the wrapper, only the first click will work and will load new content into the #wrapper. But the next clicks won't work, when the content of  #wrapper is replaced, it won't work anymore.

Comment: I used your code except `container.on("click", "#test a", function() {` and I added `return false;` . [I do not often post on SO so I don't know how to paste my updated code. I'm sorry if I'm not clear enough]

Comment: So if you are updating the html then second solution would have worked for you. Correct?

Comment: You are right, I added your second solution and it worked, I'm very thankful.

Comment: glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should post your DOM/Html file also...
Probably its a problem with the selection of the trigger.
Try to select it with a class:

```
<a class="trigger-button">Click Me</a>


var trigger = $('.trigger-button')
```